# JSON array parameters in URL

Tags: json, url

JSON string `fields:{"NAME":"Andrew"}` is equal to the URL-string `fields[NAME]=Andrew`

The question is what is the correct URL form for this JSON string?
`"PHONE": [ { "VALUE": "555888", "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK" } ]`
How to show the value, that contains key-value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "PHONE" is an array with 1 parameter

```
fields[PHONE][0][VALUE]
```

[ ] brackets defines array and { } - object with attributes.

For example

```
[ { }, { } ]
```

is array with 2 objects within it.